# Потеря фокуса в EditText после добавления в ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

Всем привет) Помогите с маленькой проблемой. При добавлении Item'a в ListView не магу сделать так чтоб EditText поддавалса редактированию.  Мой Item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_rowSpan="3">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom|left|right|top"
        android:src="@mipmap/happyface" />
</FrameLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView25"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:text="Длина"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView26"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:text="Ширина"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView27"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:text="Количество"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="numberSigned"
    android:maxLength="@integer/maxDigitsInputDetail"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="100"
    android:textIsSelectable="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:inputType="numberSigned"
    android:maxLength="@integer/maxDigitsInputDetail"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="100"
    android:textIsSelectable="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:inputType="numberSigned"
    android:maxLength="@integer/maxDigitsInputDetail"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="1"
    android:textIsSelectable="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView28"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="3"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:text="мм"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView29"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="3"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:text="мм"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView30"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="3"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:text="шт."
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView32"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

ListView:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

И код самого Activity:

```
public class detailListOfMaterial extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

Button addNewDetail;
TextView TopNameOfMaterial;
//-----------------
ListView listView;
private static final int CM_DELETE_ID = 1;
SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter;
ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(
        LocalInfo.getOrders().size());
Map<String, Object> m;
final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME_DETAIL_lENGTH = "LENGTH";
final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME_DETAIL_WIDTH = "WIDTH";
final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME_DETAIL_COUNT = "COUNT";
final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME_DETAIL_ID = "ID";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_list_of_material);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    addNewDetail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    addNewDetail.setOnClickListener(this);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView4);
    TopNameOfMaterial = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView31);
    TopNameOfMaterial.setText("Список деталей");
    DetailorUtils.setIdOfDetailUsesInMaterial(LocalInfo.getIdWorkMaterial(), LocalInfo.getIdWorkOrder());
    for (int i = 0; i < LocalInfo.getIdPositionDetailUsedInMaterial().size(); i++) {
        m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_DETAIL_lENGTH, LocalInfo.getWorkOrder().getDetails().get(LocalInfo.getIdPositionDetailUsedInMaterial().get(i)).getLength());
        m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_DETAIL_WIDTH, LocalInfo.getWorkOrder().getDetails().get(LocalInfo.getIdPositionDetailUsedInMaterial().get(i)).getWidth());
        m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_DETAIL_COUNT, LocalInfo.getWorkOrder().getDetails().get(LocalInfo.getIdPositionDetailUsedInMaterial().get(i)).getAmount());
        m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_DETAIL_ID, LocalInfo.getWorkOrder().getDetails().get(LocalInfo.getIdPositionDetailUsedInMaterial().get(i)).getIdDetail());
        data.add(m);
    }
    String[] from = {ATTRIBUTE_NAME_DETAIL_lENGTH, ATTRIBUTE_NAME_DETAIL_WIDTH,
            ATTRIBUTE_NAME_DETAIL_COUNT, ATTRIBUTE_NAME_DETAIL_ID};
    int[] to = {R.id.editText2, R.id.editText3, R.id.editText4, R.id.textView32};
    simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.unitlist_detail, from, to);
    listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    registerForContextMenu(listView);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case (R.id.button7): {
            Detail detail = new Detail();
            detail.setIdOrder(LocalInfo.getIdWorkOrder());
            detail.setLength(100);
            detail.setWidth(100);
            detail.setIdMaterial(LocalInfo.getIdWorkMaterial());
            detail.setAmount(1);
            detail.setIdDetail((int) new Date().getTime());
            LocalInfo.getWorkOrder().getDetails().add(detail);
            LocalInfo.setOrders(LocalInfo.getOrders());
            m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_DETAIL_lENGTH, detail.getLength());
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_DETAIL_WIDTH, detail.getWidth());
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_DETAIL_COUNT, detail.getAmount());
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_DETAIL_ID, detail.getIdDetail());
            data.add(m);
            simpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    Intent intent =new Intent(this, detailMain.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, CM_DELETE_ID, 0, "Видалити");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == CM_DELETE_ID) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        Log.v("position", String.valueOf(acmi.position));
        String _id = data.get(acmi.position).get("ID").toString();
        for(int i=0;i<LocalInfo.getWorkOrder().getDetails().size();i++){
            if(LocalInfo.getWorkOrder().getDetails().get(i).getIdDetail()==Integer.parseInt(_id)){
                LocalInfo.getWorkOrder().getDetails().remove(i);
            }
        }
        LocalInfo.setOrders(LocalInfo.getOrders());
        data.remove(acmi.position);
        simpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

При добавлении нового Item'a в ListView - диалоговое меню для Item срабатывает но нет доступа для редактирования EditText'ов, но если контекстное меню убрать - есть возможность для редактирования. ПРобывал варианты с `android:focusable="false"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`
или лучше диалоговое меню приэтом быбросить куданибудь в другое место? Тут один "может" нюанс - клик по Item это переход на другую Activity

Answer (score 1):

Напишите свой адаптер, а не используйте системный. А ещё лучше - на `RecyclerView` перейдите. И не вешайте слушатель на элементы снаружи адаптера - это делать надо в адаптере, в`getView`

И вы не сможете сделать так, чтобы EditText работал и на ввод и на перенаправление в активити. Последнее надо повестить на к-л другой элемент разметки элемента списка